# Is there any way to get previous page url in silverlight navigation application

Tags: silverlight, navigation, navigationservice

Is there any way to get previous page url in silverlight navigation application.
I am using navigation Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get the navigation history, you can store it by yourself by listening the navigation service event [NavigationService.Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (or [Frame.Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.frame.navigated%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for frame navigation).

```
private List<Uri> _navigationHistory = new List<Uri>();

void  onNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    _navigationHistory.Add(e.Uri);
}

private Uri getBackUri()
{
        return _navigationHistory.Count > 1
            ? _navigationHistory[_navigationHistory.Count - 2]
            : null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks tonio... i have used navigation parameter :)but your response also helps me..thanks :)

Comment: I have got an idea that there is no other way to get previous url except saving that to some list in silverlight :(

Answer (score -1):

There is a way through which you can get URL of previous page before postback.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
 Session["PrvPageUrl"] = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
}
```

It might be help you.

Comment: It's not for Silverlight application Raj is using navigation Service with Silverlight ;)