# How to get the last navigation url in silverlight application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I have problem in finding the last navigation url.

From Page A i am going to Page B. When clicking on back button on page B will take me back to Page A. My question is how to i get the last page(Page B) url in Page A.

Any one can help me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered previously on SO:

[Is there any way to get previous page url in silverlight navigation application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16392316/is-there-any-way-to-get-previous-page-url-in-silverlight-navigation-application)

---

The accepted answer was:

> There is no way to get the navigation history, you can store it by
>   yourself by listening the navigation service event
>   [NavigationService.Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigated%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) (or [Frame.Navigated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.frame.navigated%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for frame
>   navigation).
>
> ```
> private List<Uri> _navigationHistory = new List<Uri>();
>
> void  onNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
> {
>     _navigationHistory.Add(e.Uri);
> }
>
> private Uri getBackUri()
> {
>     return _navigationHistory.Count > 1
>         ? _navigationHistory[_navigationHistory.Count - 2]
>         : null;
> }
> ```